# spring Boot SSE: How to dispose connection when client close the connection?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I have a Spring Boot 3 SSE service providing information.

- When a client is connected to it, e.g. a Chrome tab or curl command
- And the client closes the connection, e.g. close the tab or hit CTRL C on the curl command
- The SSE continues to emit data to this SSE connection, once it doesn't know that it was closed by the client side

What should I do to close this connection after some time of inactivity?

my code:

```html
@RestController
public class StreamingUpdatesController {

    private final Service service;

    @GetMapping(value = "/stream/{id}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<EventTO> stream(@PathVariable final String id) {
        return service.events(id, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    }


}
```

Thanks.

Sergio.